# Data type of reference variable

Tags: c#

Consider the following declaration:

```
Class1 c1=new Class1();
```

[image: stack and heap]

The reference variable `c1` is kept in the stack and the actual object is allocated in the heap.

What is the type of this "reference variable" `c1` in the stack? Is it an integer pointer pointing to memory address of the heap?

Comment: The type as far as C# is concerned is "Class1". The value is a reference. Whether that's a simple pointer or something else is implementation-specific.

Comment: check this out https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t63sy5hs.aspx Or http://www.albahari.com/valuevsreftypes.aspx

Comment: It's a _fat pointer_: address with other details required at runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, `c1` is not necessarily sitting on the stack.  It's a value, and that value will sit wherever that variable is stored.  It might be on the stack, it might not, there are lots of factors that influence where a given variable is stored.

As far as what the type of the variable is, the type of the variable `c1` is `Class1`.  That the value of that variable is a reference to an object that is elsewhere, rather than the data comprising a `Class1` instance *is what it means to have a variable of type `Class1`*.  By *definition* a storage location that contains a reference to an instance of type `Class1` that is elsewhere is what it means to have a variable of type `Class1`, and that's exactly what `c1` is.

Comment: Thanks Servy. I got it now.